# Integration involving Gamma function

Tags: calculus

$\int_0^t e^{-\lambda x} x^{n-1} \ dx$

I know that $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-\lambda x} x^{n-1} = \frac{\Gamma(n)}{\lambda^n}$ but am not sure how to do it with the $t$ upper limit.

Comment: See the [incomplete gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) not so easy to handle...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As  Raymond Manzoni commented, the result involves the  incomplete gamma function which is not the most pleasant to handle.

For $n \gt 0$, the result is $$\int_0^t e^{-\lambda x} x^{n-1} \ dx=\frac{\Gamma (n)-\Gamma (n,t \lambda )}{\lambda^n}$$ in which the second piece goes to $0$ for large values of $t$.

For large values of $x$ $$\Gamma (n,x ) =e^{-x} x^n \left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{n-1}{x^2}+\frac{(n-1) (n-2)}{x^3}+\frac{(n-1)
   (n-2) (n-3)}{x^4}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^5\right)\right)$$